# I want to make this code to work for two variables it only copies data of cell A1 in column B i want it to record data of cell C1 in column D as well?

Tags: excel, vba

In then "ThisWorkbook" module, paste :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
     'Stop execution when workbook closes
    On Error Resume Next 
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul", , False 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     'start execution when workbook opens
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Calcul"
```

in a module, paste :

```
Public Heure As Date 
Sub Calcul() 
    Heure = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00") 
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul" 
    Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = [A1] 
End Sub
```

I want to make this code to work for two variables it only copies data of cell A1 in column B i want it to record data of cell C1 in column D as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to this:

```
With [B65536].End(xlUp)(2)
    .Item(1, 1) = [A1]
    .Item(1, 3) = [C1]
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Replace `Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = [A1]` with:

```
With Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
   .Value = [A1]
   .Offset(0,3).Value = [C1]
End With
```